# NSFileManager enumeratorAtURL doesn't work properly on XCode 6 / iOS 8

Tags: ios8, xcode6

I'm on Mavericks.

I'm using the simulator.

It appears that NSFileManager URL based methods don't work properly on XCode 6 / iOS 8.

In my code sample at bottom, the path being searched in 'directoryToScan' is ...
/Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A092C58C-1A43-4AF3-A9B1-109D7BA27F8D/data/Containers/Data/Application/41232C14-CF90-4E5C-72A7-8FF464FE7C32/Documents

In the code at bottom, even though I have files at the path I'm providing, when my code reaches the "for in" enumerator, it jumps right over the "for in" block to the end of it, and continues at the next line, and I get NO ERROR message from the block in the errorHandler.
I also tried a while clause, and that did the same.

Also, I tried two other techniques...

```
// THIS DOES NOT WORK
NSArray *dirContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:directoryToScan includingPropertiesForKeys:nil options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles error:&theError];

// THIS DOES WORK            
NSArray *dirContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentDirectory error:&theError];
```

So it appears there's a problem with NSURL's in iOS 8.

Any idea what's going on?  I would think if there were a permission issue, I would have seen an error in my handler.

```
NSURL *directoryToScan = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:documentDirectory];

NSDirectoryEnumerator *dirEnumerator = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtURL:directoryToScan
                                                                    includingPropertiesForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSURLIsDirectoryKey, nil]
                                                                                       options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles | NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsSubdirectoryDescendants | NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsPackageDescendants
                                                                                  errorHandler:^(NSURL *url, NSError *error){
                                                                                      NSLog(@"Error occurred at url %@",url);
                                                                                      NSLog(@"Error message is %@",error);
                                                                                      return YES;}];

for (NSURL *theURL in dirEnumerator)
{
  // Work with the files found by dirEnumerator.
  // This whole block is being skipped over.
}
```

Comment: Yip I too am having the exact same issue. No resolution as yet.

Comment: Yip. Still broken on iOS 8 GM.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still interesting in investigating the issue can You please provide the code for setting `directoryToScan` and `documentDirectory`? Have you tried to print both values during debug to ensure they both address same directory? In Xcode 6.1?
In Xcode 6.1 both `for (NSURL *theURL in dirEnumerator)` and `for (NSURL* theURL = [dirEnumerator nextObject])` work fine for me.